# Select2 works only on localhost, on server doesnt works - with codeigniter

Tags: jquery-select2

If Anybody can help me with this error, I'll appreciate so much.
is there a trick with my htaccess or direct to my code?

---

My Controller called jasontrend

class Jsontrend extends CI_Controller {

```
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    public function index()
    {


        $input = (isset($_GET['term']))? trim($_GET['term']) : '';
        $return_arr = array();
        $row_array  = array();
        $query = $this
            ->db
            ->order_by('slug','ASC')
            ->like('slug', $input)
            ->get('trendmark');

            foreach($query->result() as $row):

                $row_array['slug']       = $row->slug;
                $row_array['id']         = $row->id;
                $row_array['titleMedia'] = utf8_encode($row->titleMedia);
                $row_array['fileMedia']  = $row->fileMedia;
                $row_array['url']        = $row->url;

                array_push($return_arr,$row_array);

            endforeach;

            header("Content-type: application/json");
            echo json_encode($return_arr);


        }
```

}

my javascript:

```
$("#epop").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    placeholder: "DIGITE A MARCA DE SEU PRODUTO",

    ajax: {
        url: top.location.host == '127.0.0.1' ? 'http://127.0.0.1/mysite/jsontrend/' : 'http://mysite/jsontrend',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (term, page) {
        return {
            term: term,
            page: page || 1

        };
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
        console.log(error + ": " + jqXHR.responseText);
        return { results: [] }; // Return dataset to load after error
    },
    results: function (data) {
        //$('.searchtrend').attr('disabled',false);

        return {
            results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                return {
                    text: item.titleMedia,
                    url: item.url,
                    id: item.id,
                    slug: item.slug,
                    file: item.fileMedia

                }

            })
        };
    }
},
formatResult: repoFormatResult,
formatSelection: repoFormatSelection,
dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop"

});
```

htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|run.php|fckeditor|assets|img|css|js|images|updin|stats|xml|admin|robots.txt|favicon.ico|favicon_adm.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: so, whats the error you get?

Comment: Simply doesnt works online... strange... Is there something that I forgot? When a I type the keyword, always bring no results found...

Comment: well, what does it say in the console of chrome/firebug? is it a cross site error? insecure content? something has to be logged as erroring

Comment: It doesn't return result. Only the message no results founds... Is there a way to discover like an alert or something?

Comment: download firebug or open chrome web dev tools, google it for more info

Answer (score 0):

Write your URL in PHP code as seen below

```
ajax: {
   url:'<?php echo base_url('yourcontroller/') ?>',
   your other code here
}
```